# Select unique value on one column then still display other columns on multi table

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using Oracle and my main objective is to display the unique value of a column from `table b` `(Field1)` but then I still need to display other columns from other tables.

```
SELECT A.FIELD1, MAX(B.FIELD1) AS "UNIQUE", B.FIELD2, B.FIELD3, C.FIELD3, D.FIELD4
FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON B.FIELD4 = A.FIELD1
INNER JOIN C ON C.FIELD2 = B.FIELD1
INNER JOIN D ON D.FIELD3 = C.FIELD3
GROUP BY A.FIELD1, B.FIELD1, B.FIELD2, B.FIELD3, C.FIELD3, D.FIELD4
ORDER BY A.FIELD1, D.FIELD4 ASC
```

The data structure is

```
A
FIELD1  FIELD2  FIELD3  FIELD4
ABC     DEF     HIJ     KLM

B
FIELD1  FIELD2  FIELD3  FIELD4
000     1X1     24D     ABC
000     1X1     301     ABC
000     1X1     135     ABC

C
FIELD1  FIELD2  FIELD3  FIELD4
112     000     24D     SFD

D
FIELD1  FIELD2  FIELD3  FIELD4
2RD     VCB     MNK     GGG
```

I want to display only one row per data, however, I cannot achieve this. Any suggestions?

Comment: 1.  `MAX(B.FIELD1)` would not return you b.field3 as 24D necessarily. As all `field1` are save, you can get any row at random. 
2. `D.FIELD3 = C.FIELD3`. This would not return anything for your scenario. Are you sure that join condition is correct

Comment: Hm. I think I did not illustrate it correctly. But basically, I want to get unique values of `B.FIELD1` even after joining other tables.

Comment: in this case, there is only 1 unique value of `B.FIELD1` but with that, why are u getting `B.FIELD3` as `24D` and not `301` or other value? What is the logic there?

Comment: it's a shame that I think I really messed up with the illustration. just don't mind the table, have edited and removed the results. do you have suggestions/tips though on achieving the objective? Thanks.

Comment: Your question is really not clear. You can search for `row_number() over (partition by ... ` clause and use that with your main query after correction. Now use an outer query and select only 1 row per partition. Unfortunately without proper sample and expected output, I can only guess what you want.

Comment: Sorry as I do not really know how to express what I want. Anyway, thanks for the tip. I will start from there.

Comment: Marked for closing as "unclear what you are asking" - if you can figure it out for yourself, please edit the question (even if it is closed, it may be reopened if you clarify what you need). Good luck!

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

I think, you have mistake in your query. You have used column `B.FIELD1` for calculating max value `MAX(B.FIELD1)` and at the same time have used this column in `GROUP BY` section.